# Does Apple MapKit JS requires membership program?

Tags: javascript, mapkit, apple-maps, apple-developer

A few weeks ago, Apple released MapKit JS (Apple Maps API for JavaScript).

I have read the documentation to try some examples, but I can not generate a key in the Apple Developer Center, I can not access "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles".

On MapKit JS documentation, Apple does not say that it is necessary to be part of the "developer membership program".

Can I use MapKit JS without it?

Comment: Only the team agent and admins can register Maps IDs and create MapKit JS private keys.

Comment: I'm admin of my account, is necessary a paid account?

Comment: For me work just fine, maybe paid account is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Apple requires you to have an apple device to develop anything for apple devices. You can use any phone for two factor verification, but you need at least one apple device to sign up for their developer program. https://developer.apple.com/maps/mapkitjs/. You have to read the enable trusted device part. I am in the process of buying an apple device just so I can use mapkit. I don't like apple!